# How to use master pom file to checkout all modules of a web application and build all modules

Tags: maven, build-automation, multi-module, build-management

I have a web application that relies on several modules. So to build it, I have a master pom.xml file. What I want this pom file to do is to checkout out all the modules. 
below is my pom file.

```
        <executions>
        <execution>
                    <id>check-out-project1</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>    
                    <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/module1</checkoutDirectory>
                    <connectionUrl>scm:svn:svn://svnserver/svn/module1/trunk</connectionUrl>
                    <!--<developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://svnserver/svn/module1/trunk</developerConnection>!-->
                    <username>username</username>                             
                    <password>password</password>             
                    </configuration>
         </execution>

          <execution>
                    <id>check-out-project2</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>    
                    <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/module1</checkoutDirectory>
                    <connectionUrl>scm:svn:svn://svnserver/svn/module1/trunk</connectionUrl>
                          <username>username</username>                             
                          <password>password</password>             
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

I have tried **mvn scm:checkout**  and **mvn scm:checkout -check-out-project1** but it give me the error:
  **Cannot run checkout command : Can't load the scm provider. You need to define a connectionUrl parameter.**

I don't understand why this is happening since I have the connectionUrl parameters defined inside the pom file already,the ideas point that I want to get to is having the pom file configured to be able to checkout multiple projects at the same time. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a maven repository to publish your artifacts to? I think you should try to have the dependency modules pre-build (and tested) before using them in your main assembly. Even if you're just using your local ~/.m2 repo. This should enable you to use maven-dependency-plugin and download directly compiled and tested artifacts (assuming you have tests).

Answer (score 3):

I found that if placing each of the checkouts into its own `<execution> ... </execution>` and within place the individual `<configuration> ... </configuration>` for them works. For example:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repo1-dependency</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <connectionUrl>${my.repo1.url}</connectionUrl>
                        <scmVersion>${my.repo1.branch}</scmVersion>
                        <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                        <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${my.repo1}-${my.repo1.branch}</checkoutDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>repo2-dependency</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <connectionUrl>${my.repo2.url}</connectionUrl>
                        <scmVersion>${my.repo2.branch}</scmVersion>
                        <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                        <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${my.repo2}-${my.repo2.branch}</checkoutDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete pom file as I have tried and I only get 1 execution and it uses the scm tag information, not the connectionUrl from the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I faced to same situation and I found a solution -using your code :D- that works on my computer:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.xxx.internet</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
    <url>http://www.mySite.de</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://svn-repo-adress:8080/repo/myDirectory</connection>
        <developerConnection>http://svn-repo-adress:8080/repo/myDirectory</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>http://svn-repo-adress:8080/repo/myDirectory</url>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.6</version>
               <configuration>
                 <goals>checkout</goals>
                 <checkoutDirectory>target/checkout</checkoutDirectory>
                 <username>username</username>
                 <password>userpassword</password>
               </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-out-project1</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>   
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

After I executed "mvn scm:checkout" on the cmd console it did work.

I think the important point was to add the scm tag first, before I had executed the build tag.