# master pom Vs aggregator pom vs parent pom

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, build-process

can any one tell me about master pom and what kind of information we can include for master pom...

aggragator pom:- means aggregating all the modules

```
    <module>A</module>
    <module>b</module>
    <module>c</module>
    <module>d</module>
```

parent pom means:- which has all config dependency plugin information...

```
properties and plugins and combination of other configurations
```

can any one tell me the master pom,how it differ to other pom....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "master POM" has anything to do with the maven official terminology.

I belieive this is a jargon specific to a project or a vendor. Where did you see this ?

Comment: i heard some people are using this word around of me,then tried to know, i swa this post ,did not got exactly....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571859/how-to-use-master-pom-file-to-checkout-all-modules-of-a-web-application-and-buil

Comment: Ok, clearly here this is not a maven terminology, the author of the question meant "multi-module project" and incorrectly named it "master"